# How to dynamically rename columns in a function in R?

Tags: r, function, functional-programming

Here is a function I'm trying to build in R

```
lag_decay_gen <- function(data,col,lag_val,decay_val)
  {
  temp <- lag(col, n = lag_val*7, default =0)
  temp <- temp + shift(temp)*decay_val
  temp <- cbind(data,temp)
  }
```

Here data = main dataset while col = column of the dataset

Generally, the input for col would something look like this - data$'column_name'

Here inside the function I would like the temp column to be renamed dynamically to

```
paste(col,lag_val,decay_val, sep = "_")
```

where col is the name of the column but this is the value under the column that I'm passing to the function and hence an error occurs.

Moreover, how should I go about building the function lag_decay_gen if my col input has multiple columns. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why are you using both `lag` and `shift` and not just one of them? And what package does `lag` come from, package `dplyr`? Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))`. (`df` is the name of your dataset.)

Comment: @RuiBarradas I'm prompting lag_val from the user and then multiplying the lag_val by 7 as I have my data on daily level. While for calculating the carryover effect of the previous day I'm using the shift function

Comment: The results with `dplyr::lag` or `data.table::shift` are `identical()`, I have just tested it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a new column in a dataframe with a name also created by the function do something like the following.

```
lag_decay_gen <- function(data, col, lag_val, decay_val){
  values <- data[[col]]
  temp <- dplyr::lag(values, n = lag_val*7, default = 0)
  temp <- temp + dplyr::lag(temp)*decay_val
  new_col <- paste(col, lag_val, decay_val, sep = "_")
  data[[new_col]] <- temp
  data
}

lag_decay_all <- function(data, cols, lag_val, decay_val){
  for(col in cols) {
    data <- lag_decay_gen(data, col, lag_val, decay_val)
  }
  data
}
```

Now test the functions. To do this I will use built-in data set `iris`.
First, to pass just one column **name**.

```
df1 <- iris[1:2]

new_df1 <- lag_decay_gen(df1, "Sepal.Length", 1, 0.5)

head(new_df1)
#  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Sepal.Length_1_0.5
#1          5.1         3.5                 NA
#2          4.9         3.0                  0
#3          4.7         3.2                  0
#4          4.6         3.1                  0
#5          5.0         3.6                  0
#6          5.4         3.9                  0
```

And to pass several column names at the same time:

```
names_cols <- names(df1)
lag_decay_all(iris[1:2], names_cols, 1, 0.5)
```

Note that function `lag_decay_all` can also be used to compute the new columns if it's one column only.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I'm afraid this isn't something I was looking for. I have re-edited the question with some more specifics

Comment: @AishwaryaSharma I don't understand, I also pass `Sepal.Length` without (double) quotes. This is not a name. What exactly is the error you are getting?

Comment: The column values for Sepal.Length_1_0.5 should be NA
7.45
9.9
12.25
14.55
17.05
with 1 lag and 0.5 decay

Comment: @AishwaryaSharma No, it shouldn't, if you pass `lag_val = 1`, it then becomes `n = 1*7` in the call to `dplyr::lag`.

Comment: Oh you're right here but I'm getting this error on running the function with these parameters **lag_decay_gen_2(data.2, data.2$TV_Impacts,1,0.4)** -  Error in `[[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, name_col, value = numeric(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 395

Comment: @AishwaryaSharma Corrected, see now.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you so much!